# Curisioty about universe

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

I am a bachelor student and I have a question going round my mind about the universe. Every one says that the universe is ever expanding and it is also said that the vast possible space is also the universe. So my point is some empty space is required for the universe to expand. Then what do we call that space? Hope someone will kill my curiosity!